# Getting values from the query string using Janrain's PHP OpenID library

Tags: php, openid, openid-provider, google-openid

I am using Janrains PHP openID library. All is working perfectly except when I try and pull values from the query string on the script that is returned to after the user is authorized.

Here is the first part of the query string:

```
http://localhost/Cloudshare/trunk/Cloudshare/php/openID/recieve_auth_request.php?    janrain_nonce=2010-11-08T22:29:59Zp9PTgs&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud.
```

I am able to get the value of the 'janrain_nonce' item on the query string, but am not able to get any values for things like 'openid.op_endpoint'..

For example, this

```
$test = $_GET["janrain_nonce"];
```

returns a value ok into $test, but the the value of $test is blank using the following...

```
$test = $_GET["openid.claimed_id"];
```

What I am trying to do is get one of the values from the query string to see if it contains 'google' or not, as I have some processing specific to Google to do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see openid.claimed_id in your querystring, but try getting $_GET['openid_claimed_id'];

testing your querystring at my [API](http://api.fatherstorm.com/?query&%20janrain_nonce=2010-11-08T22:29:59Zp9PTgs&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud.)  seems to indicate that the "." is being converted to "_" FWIW

I've confirmed that. var.var2 gets converted to var_var2   see

[http://api.fatherstorm.com/?query&test_is[]=1&test.is[]=2](http://api.fatherstorm.com/?query&test_is%5b%5d=1&test.is%5b%5d=2)